# Angular Js..., ng-click function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs, my problem is that when I clicked the button that I append it doesn't call the function or the function doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
</tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.name"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.email"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.number"/></td>
        <td colspan="2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="addContact()">Add Contact</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
        <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeContact(contact._id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="editContact(contact._id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
$scope.editContact = function(id){
    $http.get('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response){
        $scope.contact = response;

        var addButton = angular.element('#custom_btn');

        addButton.empty();

        addButton.append('<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="update()">Update Contact</buton>');
    });
};

$scope.update = function(){
    alert('test');
};
```

what is wrong with my code. my idea is that it is the same with jQuery.. where all elements appended by jquery will have a `body` on its function call..

thanks in advance.

Comment: please put your html code,in order to see what's going on in the view

Comment: please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542) before starting out with Angular - it will save you a lot of headache

Comment: is it a typo?: you have `addContact()` but your real function is `editContact()`

Comment: @soroushgholamzadeh no.., no error in the code but when the button change..  to update... the ng-click doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the editContact() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please read this [discusstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542).

You can use `ng-if` directive in the html view instead of JQuery:

```
<tr>
...
    <td colspan="2" id="custom_btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="addContact()">Add Contact</button>
        <button ng-if="isEdited" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="update()">Update Contact</buton>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in the `editContact` function:

```
$http.get('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response){
    $scope.contact = response;

    $scope.isEdited = true;
});
```

**Note:** if you got error for `update()` use `$parent.update()` in the view.